# Ruby on Rails has_many through from multiple sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations, has-many-through

I have a class of User

A user can have multiple files, the File class has a user_id column. The requirement is now that users can share files with other users.

So a user can have their own files and be able to view and edit files that belong to other users.

My basic idea was to create a SharedFile association and use

```
has_many :files
has_many :shared_files
has_many :files, through: shared_files
```

However when calling @user.files this only returns a collection of the shared files and not any of the files owned by the user. Is there a way to merge the two collections?

I know I am missing a step or this may not be the correct way to go about it at all

Comment: The problem is that the method `.files` for user has to do one or the other. It can't do both at the same time. If you already have access to user files, why do you need to get access to them through `shared_files`? I assume all `shared_files` are also just `files`. If you want to get just the shared files for a user, you would set define a scope which selects based upon the file being shared.

Comment: shared_files is an association. The original app a user has_many files. With the new requirement files have and belong to many users.